# AsyncTask - Can't connect via sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I am trying to establish a connection between an Android Application and a Python script via sockets.

This Java code works absolutely fantastic with my Python server.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Socket s=new Socket("localhost",5000);
            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            s.close();
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

However, when I try to implement it in my Android application (see below), I have the feeling that the `doInBackground()` is not even called:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        Connect myConnect = new Connect();
        myConnect.execute();

        String myResult = Integer.toString(myConnect.getResult());

        myText.setText(myResult);
    }
}


class Connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    int result = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        result = 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            result = 2;
            Socket s=new Socket("localhost",5000);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            s.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            result = -1;
            return -1;
        }
        result = 3;
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

    int getResult(){
        return result;
    }
}
```

[image]

What am I missing here to make it work?

Comment: you are missing what `localhost` means ... asked bazillion times use search ... hint: does python's script is running on device/emulator itself? no? then why are you using localhost?

Comment: `localhost` points to `myself`.  So calling `localhost` on emulator will try to connect to emulator. Calling it on the PC will connect to PC. Calling it on the Android device will try to connect to `itself`. Are you running the server on the emulator as well? ofcource you don't .

Comment: In addition, as you might expect `AsyncTask` runs asynchronously from your main thread. By the time you call `getResult`, `doInBackground` is not running yet or did not set the result yet, even if the address was correctly specified

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE Very good point, but it never hits the server: C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/VWKY61Q/PycharmProjects/Sockets/server.py
0.0000 - Starting server
0.0320 - Opening port localhost at 5000
0.0320 - Server established
0.0320 - Waiting for client

Comment: @VladMatvienko I added the actual IP but nothing happened

Comment: @Selvin Because I didn't know it doesn't work like that. :-)

Comment: You should use onPostExecute to put the result of doInBackGround in your TextView.

Comment: which exactly `actual IP` have you added? there are currently multiple since you use internet (1st), virtual network with emulator(2nd), possibly local network (3rd). So you need to use your `real Ip` from virtual network with emulator

Comment: `Socket s=new Socket("localhost",5000);`. That should be `Socket s=new Socket("10.0.2.2",5000);` when using an emulator.

Comment: `catch(Exception e){
            result = -1;
            return -1;
        }`. You are throwing away valuble informatian as you should add e.printStarckTrace() there. You should also log e.getMessage() as that gives you the cause of the exception. Also you should change the type of `result` from int to String as then you can add a statement in the catch block like result = e.getMessage() and display that result in onPostExecute. All those numbers are not very informative.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks! The IP you said did the trick. Thanks also for the tip with e.printStackTrace(). I would be happy to accept an answer if you could post one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Socket s=new Socket("localhost",5000);.
```

That should be

```
Socket s=new Socket("10.0.2.2",5000);
```

when using an emulator.